# Ropsten rejects my sendSignedTransaction function

Tags: web3js, transactions, ropsten, error

This is my code:

```
    contractNoEvents.methods.myMethod().call(function(err,foo){
           if (foo.length > n) {
             contractNoEvents.methods.myOtherMethod().call(async function(er, bar){
               if (bar.length > 10){


                var nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account);
                const encoded_tx = contractNoEvents.methods.mySendMethod(Math.floor(n).encodeABI();
                const rawTx = {
                     nonce: nonce,
                     gasLimit: 3000000,
                     gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(utils.toWei('20', 'gwei')), 
                     data: encoded_tx,
                     from: account,
                     to: contractAddress
                }

                let tx = new Tx(rawTx);
                tx.sign(pvtKey);
                let serializedTx = tx.serialize();
                console.log(serializedTx);
                web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
                .on('receipt', console.log)
                .on('error', console.log);
               }
              });
           }
        });
```

I get the following error on Ropsten:

```
connection not open on send()
(node:1983) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 13): Error: connection not open
```

I've been looking around but could not find anything I'm absolutely clueless if anyone has any solutions please =)

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was the fact that

```
var nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account);
```

Was not accepted anymore when uploaded to ropsten somehow. 
I replaced it with:

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account).then(_nonce => {
  // insert the transaction signing function
}
```